# JavaScript filter that stops at the first result

Tags: javascript, arrays, list

Is there a mechanism in JavaScript (without having to write my own) similar to `filter`. Instead of returning all the filtered elements of a collection though, it only returns the first one. Of course I could do the following to get the first even number:

```
[7,5,3,2,1].filter(x => x % 2 == 0)[0]
```

But if there were 10 million more numbers in that list, there'd be a lot of unnecessary work. In a language like Haskell, the other 10 million numbers wouldn't be looked at due to lazy evaluation.

Is there a mechanism in JavaScript to do the above without evaluating any elements after the first result?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You can try `.find`:

```
[7,5,3,2,1].find(x => x % 2 == 0);
// result: 2
```

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

> The find() method returns a value of the first element in the array
> that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise undefined is
> returned.

**Simple benchmark**

```
var arr = [...Array(10000)].map( (item, idx) => idx )

arr.filter(i => i == 3000)[0]
arr.find(i => i == 3000)

/*
  arr.filter x 1,358 ops/sec ±0.40% (91 runs sampled)
  arr.find x 23,743 ops/sec ±0.40% (90 runs sampled)
  Fastest is arr.find
*/
```

Answer (score 7):

I think `Array.prototype.find()` accomplishes this - it will retrieve the first element in an array that matches a certain criteria:

```
[7, 5, 3, 2, 1].find(isEvenNumber); //2

function isEvenNumber(elem) {
  return elem % 2 === 0;
}
```

Comment: Your example would be more informative if it included a second even number.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to expand on the `find` solution by adding:

```js
[array.find(x => x % 2 === 0)].filter(x => x !== undefined)
```

`find` returns `undefined` if no matching entry is found, so it's not *entirely* '`filter` that stops', since `filter` will return an empty array.

This is obviously entirely dependent on what your expected output is: an array containing all results, with an empty array being a valid result, or one result that would need to be invalid (like `undefined`).