# how to pull out one entry from an array and store in a constant (not in a new array)

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to filter through an array of objects and i want to store a matching object in a constant.

I have tried using the `filter()` method, however this is storing the result of the filter in a new array.
The way the program is designed, i know there will only be one match from the filter method. Rather than storing the matching object in a new array of one object, it would be much easier for me to be able to have that object stored in a constant. Is there a method which allows me to do this?

Comment: const item=somearray.filter()[0]  ?

Comment: I'm not allowed to leave comments, but this post is pretty good. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41754839/javascript-filter-that-stops-at-the-first-result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the find() method which returns the value of the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function.

```
let array = [5, 12, 8, 130, 44];

const found = array.find(function(element) {
  return element > 10;
});
```

Or using lambda function:

```
const found = array.find(x => x > 10);
```